# What does the symbol $\otimes$ mean?

Tags: notation

I am familiar with the direct sum of sets, $\oplus$.

Comment: In what context? In some contexts, it means tensor product.

Comment: More generally, this list can be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: The direct sum of sets?!?

Comment: The $\otimes$ symbol usually means 'some multiplicative binary operation', which may differ depending on context.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The $\otimes$ symbol is used for the [tensor product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product).