# In category theory, what does the $\otimes$ symbol mean?

Tags: category-theory, notation

[The Wikipedia page for *Monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_(category_theory)) includes the $\otimes$ symbol. Example:

[image]

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31518/what-does-the-symbol-otimes-mean) I see that this symbol is used to denote a tensor product.

What does $\otimes$ mean in the context of category theory?

Comment: It's part of the definition of a monoidal category (in much the same way "$\cdot$" is part of the definition of a group).

Comment: You know you can use MathJax in the title of your question, right? (Edited)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the *tensor product* (also known as the *monoidal product*) of the monoidal category in which the monoid lives.

The Wikipedia page you link to says:

> ...a **monoid** (or **monoid object**) $(M, \mu, \eta)$ in a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) $(C, \otimes, I)$ is..."

So the meaning of $\otimes$ is being specified here. And if you click through to the page on *monoidal category*, you'll find out the definition.